# how to prevent buffer overflow

Tags: internet

Is there a way to prevent buffer overflow on applications. For example, an internet browser.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: When does this happen? My computer only stack overflows...

Comment: @ivo: you've never overflown a buffer?  you're missing out, dude!

Comment: I once flew over the cuckoo's nest though! @~quack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Firefox(Or, indeed, and other open source browser, like Chromium), you can rewrite any vulnerable parts of code yourself, and submit it as a fix. If figuring out a several thousand line codebase isn't your cup of tea, you can at least try to limit the potential damage something can do, with software such as Sandboxie.

Comment: thanks, not really a programming question. And your answer was just the answer I'm looking for.